# Why can Django not load Auth module?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I'm currently experimenting with setting up an Django app with apache + mod_wsgi for the app and using nginx for the static files. I had the app working and now wanted to add authentication, so to control serving static files.

I can still load my `index.html`, but when I try login or admin I get an ImportError "No module named auth".

I have checked and it's in the settings and in the template login. I don't know what the problem is, maybe anyone has an idea what might be wrong.

ERROR PAGE

```
ImportError at /admin/
No module named auth
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.1.1:8080/admin/
Django Version: 1.5
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named auth
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 35
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flup-1.0.3.dev_20110405-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol',
 '/home/christian/public_html/django_nginx_test/private/test_project',
 '/home/christian/public_html/django_nginx_test/private']
```

SETTINGS.PY

```
# Django settings for test_project project.

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'django_nginx_test',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '###',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '###',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = 'http://127.0.1.1:8081/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '___'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'test_project.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'test_project.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/home/christian/public_html/django_nginx_test/private/test_project/templates/test_app'
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'test_app',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

URLS.PY of Project

```
from django.conf.urls import *

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', include('test_app.urls')),
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'test_project.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^test_project/', include('test_project.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^login/$', 'auth.views.login_user'),
)
```

URLS.PY from APP

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('test_app.views',

    url(r'^$', 'index'),
)
```

Comment: Add your relevant settings.py details and your relevant urls.py entries to verify it is set up correctly. It is almost certainly a settings/urls issue.

Comment: In your urls.py you have `url(r'^login/$', 'auth.views.login_user'),` but don't have django.contrib.auth imported. Is this a package (app) you created? If so, I would suggest renaming it to alleviate confusion with imports of `django.contrib.auth`. That way we can see which `auth` it is having an issue importing.

Comment: Hi, it's not an app I created, but supposed to use the standard auth module. I found this in a tutorial.

Comment: Gotcha, Mark Lavin is correct below, then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the full path to the view assuming this is meant to be the `django.contrib.auth`.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Other urls are here
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
)
```

If you are included multiple views from the same module then you can include a common in the first part of the pattern.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('django.contrib',
    # Other urls are here
    url(r'^login/$', 'auth.views.login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'auth.views.logout'),
)
```